# How to split a nested list inside a Pandas Dataframe column vertically,ie, into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a Dataframe, I want to split Co2 rowise  :

```
Co1 Co2
1 [{'link':'http:abc.com'},{'link':'http:def.com'}]
2 [{'link':'http:ghi.com'},{'link':'http:lmn.com'}]
```

Expected output

```
Co1 Co2
1 http:abc.com
1 http:def.com
2 http:ghi.com
2 http:lmn.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with dicionary of `DataFrame` created in list comprehension and join by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for extract column:

```
import ast

#if values are string repr of lists
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x)) for k, x in df.pop('Co2').items()}
#if values are lists of dicts
#dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(x) for k, x in df.pop('Co2').items()}

df = df.join(pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Co1          link
0    1  http:abc.com
1    1  http:def.com
2    2  http:ghi.com
3    2  http:lmn.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
#df['Co2'] = df['Co2'].apply(ast.literal_eval) : if Co2 are not actual lists
out = df.explode('Co2').assign(Co2 = lambda x: 
                              x['Co2'].str.get('link')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(out) 

   Co1           Co2
0    1  http:abc.com
1    1  http:def.com
2    2  http:ghi.com
3    2  http:lmn.com
```